# Type conversion for LPUNKNOWN

Tags: c++, types, type-conversion

How to convert LPUNKNOWN pDlg type to our class type. is dynamic_cast is fine?
Ex: myclass * myclass_obj;
myclass_obj=dynamic_cast < myclass* > pdlg;
Please help me on this.

Comment: I've already given an answer, but the missing piece of information is how and where did your code come to get an LPUNKNOWN pointer? Knowing how you got the pointer, and the inheritance model of you `myclass` type (including what it inherits from) is important to know for a proper answer.

Answer (score 3):

LPUNKNOWN is an [IUnknown pointer instance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680509(v=vs.85).aspx). - that is a COM object.  You don't typically cast a COM interface back to a specific C++ class. Instead, you invoke QueryInterface on it to get to the **interface** that you need.

You didn't specify how or where you got the LPUNKNOWN from, or how an instance of your C++ class originated to become that instance.  That would be helpful to know.

Example:

```
IUnknown *pUnk = <initialized from where ever>
IFoo *pFoo = nullptr;
HRESULT hr = pUnk->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IFoo), &pFoo);
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    pFoo->DoWhatever();
}
```

You could possibly cast it directly if the COM interface originated from within the same process, but that would not be the correct semantics for using a COM object.

Comment: Upvoted since it is the canonic way to use COM interfaces, but there are use cases for dynamic cast. For example, when in the code of a `CMyClass` (COM class) you get a pointer to the interface (`IMyClass`) you do: `CMyClass *myObj = dynamic_cast<CMyClass *>(ifoo)` to get access to the private members.

Comment: @SergeBallesta - Agreed. You should only do a direct cast on IUnknown when you are familiar enough with COM to know what you are doing. By asking the question, the OP is revealing he doesn't know enough about COM to safely do this this.

Comment: Note that my example did not directly cast an `IUnknown` but the correct interface. But I agree with you OP should have provided more information. I wanted to just answer *it is fine provided you know why you can do it* but your answer was already there  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Presumably your class is written using ATL?

In that case, what I normally do is declare a private interface like this:

```
interface __declspec(uuid("*some GUID here*")) ICheckMyClass : IUnknown
{
    STDMETHOD_(MyClass*,GetMyClass)() PURE;
};
```

and then implement that interface in my class:

```
class MyClass
    : CComObjectRootEx ...
    , private ICheckMyClass
{
...
private:
    STDMETHODIMP_(MyClass*,GetMyClass)() { return this; }

    BEGIN_COM_MAP(MyClass)
        ...
        COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(ICheckMyClass)
    END_COM_MAP()
};
```

Finally, where you need to securely cast from IUnknown*:

```
ATL::CComQIPtr<ICheckMyClass> check(pDlg);
MyClass* myClass=(check==0)?0:check->GetMyClass();
```

This may seem long-winded, but to me it has the benefit of staying within standard COM and ATL mechanisms, and doesn't require runtime type information, which is not always supported on all platforms.

Comment: You can also add `COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(MyClass)` directly to the BEGIN_COM_MAP section.  Then add a MIDL attribute to the header declaration for MyClass if the ATL wizard didn't add it for you. Then you can easily QueryInterface or use the ATL CComPtr classes to get a direct pointer to the class instance.